# Any limitation to block website using content blocker extension in mobile Safari

Tags: ios, swift, mobile-safari, safari-content-blocker

i have more then fifteen thousand of website and i want block using content blocker extension in son formate like this

```
[{
  "action":

        { "type": "block" },

  "trigger":

        { "url-filter": ".*apple.*" }

  },

  {
  "action":

       { "type": "block" },

  "trigger":

      {  "url-filter": ".*facebook.*" }
  },

  {
  "action":

      { "type": "block" },

  "trigger":

      {  "url-filter": ".*twitter.*" }
  },

  {
  "action":

        { "type": "block" },

  "trigger":

        {  "url-filter": ".*funny videos.*" }
}]
```

some website are already blocked when i load all website then no one is block, so, want to know any limitation to block website plz give me any solution     Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can have up to 50.000 filter rules.